# $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ x^nf(x) =0$ for all non negative integer n. Then $f$ will be identically $0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

If $f$ belongs to $C[-\pi, \pi]$  &  $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ x^nf(x) =0$     for all non negative integer n. Then $f$ will be identically $0$.

How to do it by stone-weierstrass theorem?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is not true. Take $f = 1_{[-\pi,0]} \cdot \sin$.

Comment: Did you mean the integral to start at zero? You need to clarify the question.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please?

Comment: @m_t_: Note the space and the limits on the integration.

Comment: Extremely sorry... I just edited the question @copper.hat  m_t_

Answer (score 1):

Using Stone-Weierstrass theorem, you know that it exists $\left(P_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of polynomial that uniformly converges to $f$.
Hence you can write that for all $\ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $\ x \in \left[-\pi,\pi\right]$
$$
\left|f(x)P_n(x)-f^2(x)\right|=\left|f(x)\right|\left|P_n(x)-f(x)\right| \leq \left\|f\right\|_{\infty, \left[-\pi,\pi\right]}\left\|P_n-f\right\|_{\infty, \left[-\pi,\pi\right]}
$$
You know that second term tends to $0$ as it is UNIFORMLY convergent. So
$$\left\|fP_n-f^2\right\|_{\infty, \left[-\pi,\pi\right]} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0$$
So we have shown that the sequence $\left(fP_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformy to $f^2$.
I let you conclude ( on $\left[0, \pi\right]$ )starting from there. ( that's not obvious to think to do that )

Comment: It is not true. How do you know that $f(x) = 0$ for $x <0$?

Comment: I proved it was the case on $\left[0,\pi\right]$, you are right. But i think he wants to show it is $0$ only on $\left[0,\pi\right]$, if not its proposition if obviously false

Comment: Yup, the question should be clarified.

Comment: Extremely sorry... I just edited the question @copper.hat